# firebase reacthook error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_repo')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

I am writing a hook to fetch userole from my realtime database in next js,I get the error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_repo').Here is how my hook looks

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";

const useAuth = () => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [role, setRole] = useState(null);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
        state
      

        
        let nodeRef;
        if (user.role === "user") {
          nodeRef = ref(db, `users/${user.uid}/role`);
        } else if (user.role === "trainer") {
          nodeRef = ref(db, `trainers/${user.uid}/role`);
        } else if (user.role === "admin") {
          nodeRef = ref(db, `admins/${user.uid}/role`);
        } else if (user.role === "nutritionist") {
          nodeRef = ref(db, `nutritionists/${user.uid}/role`);
        }

        onValue(nodeRef, (snapshot) => {
          const userRole = snapshot.val();
          setRole(userRole);
        });
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(null);
        setRole(null);
        // Redirect to login page if user is not logged in
        router.push("/login");
      }
    });

    
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return { currentUser, role };
};

export default useAuth;
```

This is how my firebase config looks

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getDatabase(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { auth, db, storage };
```

here is my database structure

```
- users
  - <user_id>
    - displayName: "User's display name"
    - email: "User's email address"
    - role: "user"
    - ...
- trainers
  - <trainer_id>
    - displayName: "Trainer's display name"
    - email: "Trainer's email address"
    - role: "trainer"
    - ...
- admins
  - <admin_id>
    - displayName: "Admin's display name"
    - email: "Admin's email address"
    - role: "admin"
    - ...
- nutritionists
  - <nutritionist_id>
    - displayName: "Nutritionist's display name"
    - email: "Nutritionist's email address"
    - role: "nutritionist"
    - ...
```

I have been trying this since it is clear I am doing something wrong with the database but I have tried reading through docs but still get the problem. I am a newbie in firebase.

Comment: Can you show where you are using `useAuth`? Also, try logging `userRole` in `onValue` and show us what you get.

Answer (score 0):

The callback provided to [`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onauthstatechanged) is invoked with a [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user) object. It doesn't have a `role` property.

This means that the following lines do nothing useful:

```js
let nodeRef;
if (user.role === "user") {
  nodeRef = ref(db, `users/${user.uid}/role`);
} else if (user.role === "trainer") {
  nodeRef = ref(db, `trainers/${user.uid}/role`);
} else if (user.role === "admin") {
  nodeRef = ref(db, `admins/${user.uid}/role`);
} else if (user.role === "nutritionist") {
  nodeRef = ref(db, `nutritionists/${user.uid}/role`);
}
```

After the lines above execute, `nodeRef` will be `undefined`, which you then feed into `onValue` which throws the error you see.

If the user's role has been added onto the [user's authentication token as a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims), you will need to fetch the user's ID token and then the desired claim.

```js
user.getIdTokenResult()
  .then(idToken => {
    const tokenRole = idToken.claims.role;
    // trust it?
    setRole(tokenRole);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // TODO: Handle token handling errors
  });
```